# Performance profiling of Razor views

Tags: c#, performance, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on a project where we render a kind of article list, with a lot of optional images and text properties and all in "fancy" non-tabular layout that is adapting to existing/missing properties and adding some randomness. Customer wanted a casual look and we ended up with a big tree of razor templates of depth 4 and 3-10 on each level. Each template is very simple and there is no "magic" going on.

During loadtests we found that for large article lists we have a perfomance problem in the view rendering. Rendering 5 articles takes 20ms, but rendering 60 takes 1s.

Is there a smart way to measure each templates rendering duration? I would like to avoid adding Stopwatches everywhere manually. Is there a framework way? Is there a recommendation somewhere on how to debug such problems in general? I could not find anything.

Comment: You could give Stack Overflow’s own [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/) a try. Although I’m not sure whether that will help you exactly in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a good solution myself:

```
public class RazorPerformanceDiagnosticListener
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, TemplatePerformanceHolder> _timers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TemplatePerformanceHolder>();

    [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.BeginInstrumentationContext")]
    public virtual void OnBeginInstrumentationContext(HttpContext httpContext, string path, int position, int length, bool isLiteral)
    {
        if (_timers.ContainsKey(path))
        {
            _timers[path].ContextDepth++;
        }
        else
        {
            _timers[path] = new TemplatePerformanceHolder(){ContextDepth = 1, Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew() };
        }
    }

    [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.EndInstrumentationContext")]
    public virtual void OnEndInstrumentationContext(HttpContext httpContext, string path)
    {
        _timers[path].ContextDepth--;

        if (_timers[path].ContextDepth == 0)
        {
            _timers[path].Stopwatch.Stop();
            //log _timers[path].Stopwatch.Elapsed
            _timers.Remove(path);
        }
    }
}

public class TemplatePerformanceHolder
{
    public Stopwatch Stopwatch;
    public int ContextDepth;
}
```

and in Startup.cs

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public void Configure(DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener)
{
    diagnosticListener.SubscribeWithAdapter(new RazorPerformanceDiagnosticListener());
}
```

If you wonder why you need to keep track of this context depth: these BeginInstrumentationContext events are triggered multiple times within one razor template (and so is is EndInstrumentationContext), so each template has a stack.

Also keep in mind that this code will get issues with concurrent requests (or parallelized template rendering). To work around it, you would need to make the HttpContext and possibly the threads id part of the Dictionary key. But I didn't need  "production ready" code, so be wary.

Based on [this](https://andrewlock.net/logging-using-diagnosticsource-in-asp-net-core/).